# how to display a listview when clicked on the item of a listview with the use of arraylist?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

i have written a program to display a listview , when i click on the item of the listview a new activity should display which has another listview

MainAactivity

Here i am passing the days array in the listview which is displaying perfectly and on itemclick another activity opens, and in my new activity i want a listview with the elements which i added in my arraylist , like when i click on monday i need only monday in my new listview , when i click on tuesday i need only tuesday in my new listview , i tried this program with the help of a textview and it works fine , but i want to try it with the help of a listview , need some help

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
final ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);


      arraylist.add("Monday"); 
      arraylist.add("Tuesday");
      arraylist.add("Wednesday"); 
      arraylist.add("Thursday");
      arraylist.add("Friday"); 
      arraylist.add("Saturday");
      arraylist.add("Sunday");


    final String[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
            "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, days);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.demo.listview.LIST");
            intent.putExtra("name", arraylist);
            intent.putExtra("name", arraylist);



            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

My List.java which has a 2nd listview in which i want the arraylist elements to be displayed one by one when i click on the specific item on the first listview

```
public class List extends Activity {
ListView lv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>)intent.getStringArrayList("name");

}
}
```

i know i am going wrong in both my activities 
any suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity, no need to have

```
   final String[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
```

You can set ArrayList directly to ArrayAdapter like this,

```
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist);
```

For onItemClick,

```
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.demo.listview.LIST");
            intent.putExtra("name", arraylist.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
```

---

For List Activity, again use,

```
final ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and inside onCreate, try this.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String day = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    arraylist.add(day);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist);
```

Let's know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Arjun : There is no need to add an arraylist in your first activity. 
If you want only the clicked item to be moved to your second activity then use
 intent.putExtra(days[position])
The onItemClick function gives the position of the item that received the click. 
Then use that extra from the intent in the second activity....But what's the need of showing a single item in a list if you know that you have only 1 item to be shown in the second activity.? Textview for your second activity is a better option.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]!  Take a moment to look through the [tour] and [help].  Your answer is a little hard to follow.  Can you edit it to make it more clear (spelling and grammar).

Comment: yes sir i know thats what i have mentioned in the description that i have tried with textview and it works but i want to try it with a listview , just a try sir , want to learn every possible way to display an item whether its a textview , listview or imageview